# Max of a Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Currently trying to solve the maximum of $1/(z- \frac{i}{2})$ on the set $k= \\{z:1 \leq |z| \leq 2 \\}$.

My plan is to say the maximum modulus principle states that the max is on the boundary (|z| = 1) - I think.

Since now $z = e^{i \theta}$ I am thinking of maximizing between $\theta = [0, 2 \pi]$.

Is this the correct process? Thanks anyone that can help.

Comment: You mean the maximum of $\left\lvert \frac{1}{z-i/2}\right\rvert$, I presume? The boundary of $k$ consists of the two circles $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert = 1\}$ and $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert = 2\}$, so you need to consider both or give an argument why only one is relevant. Of course, the maximum and the point where it is attained is easily found geometrically.

Comment: The question given does simply state to find the maximum of the function as I've given it above. Although I am leaning towards your thinking that it is the modulus...

Would there be a way to do it without it being the absolute value?

Comment: Without modulus, maximum makes no sense, there is no canonical order on $\mathbb{C}$, and there cannot be one compatible with its field structure.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for that I'm gonna have another go now :)

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, find the minimum of $\left| z - \frac{i}{2}\right|$.

$\left| z - \frac{i}{2} \right|$ is the distance on the complex plane from $z$ to the point $\frac{i}{2}$.  Therefore, we *expect* it will be minimized when $z = i$.

How do we prove it?  Well, $z = i$ gives $\left| z - \frac{i}{2} \right| = \frac12$.
So we want to prove that for all $z$ with $1 \le |z| \le 2$,
$$
\left| z - \tfrac{i}{2} \right| \ge \frac12
$$
Use triangle inequality:
$$
\left| z - \tfrac{i}{2} \right| \ge |z| - \left| \tfrac{i}{2} \right| \ge 1 - \frac12 = \frac12.
$$